What is the Chaya?
The medresh (Bereshit Rabba 14:9 - see full passage, as well as related Midrash Devarim Rabba 2:37; see also Zohar I 206a-207b, for example) records that the soul is composed of 5 levels:

ואהבת את ה' אלהיך בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך (דברים ו, ה), מהו בכל לבבך ובכל
נפשך, בכל נפש ונפש שברא בך. אמר רבי מאיר על כל נשימה ונשימה שאדם מעלה
חיב לקלס את יוצרו, מנין, שנאמר (תהלים קנ, ו): כל הנשמה תהלל יה. אמר
רבי סימון, חמשה שמות נקראו לנפש, ואלו הן: רוח, נפש, נשמה, חיה,
יחידה
"And you shall love Hashem your God with all your heart and with all
your soul" (Devarim 6:5). What does it mean 'with all your heart and
with all your soul'? It means with every soul that He has created
within you. Rabbi Meir said, 'For every breath a person takes, he is
obligated to praise his Creator.' From where is this derived? As it is
stated (Tehillim 150:6), 'Let every soul praise Hashem.' Rabbi Simon
said, 'Five names are given to the soul, and they are: Ruach,
Nefesh, Neshama, Chaya, and Yechida.' [Devarim Rabba
2:37]

One of those levels is Chaya.

חַיָּה, שֶׁכָּל הָאֵבָרִים מֵתִים וְהִיא חַיָּה בַּגּוּף.
Chaya: As all the bodily organs die, while it lives on ("chaya") in the body. [Bereshit Rabba 14:9]

What is the Chaya?

Any and all information to help me build a grounded and intuitive understanding of the Chaya is welcome, but generally hoping to find a much better explanation than I have found so far, so hoping to find some new high quality sources if possible.

According to Moshe Miller:

The soul merges into a state of complete nullification of the ego… The aspect of the soul called Chaya gazes upon the Divine energy of the world of Atzilut. Whereas the primary activity of the level of Neshama is to use intellectual comprehension in order to come to communion with G‑d as the Creator of the worlds, the level of Chaya communes with G‑d as He transcends the worlds. Here the soul's knowledge is not in the immanence of Divine attributes which identify the nature of the Divine energy manifested in Creation, but rather with knowing what G‑d is not — i.e. how He is not limited or defined by the finite universe. Thus the soul merges into a state of complete nullification of the ego. There is no self-seeking and no self-identity outside of G‑d. Chaya is called loving G‑d "with all one's being" (Deut. 6:5). This is knowledge of the absolute truth of things.

Makor:

Chaya


Yes—the post links to an article by Moshe Miller

Please [edit] to say explicitly whom the quotation is from and who they are. It would be even better to summarize the information from the cited work in your own words. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/

This is an interesting question dealing with how to conceptualize these abstract Torah concepts found particularly in kabbalistic and chassidic teachings.
To have a better comprehension of this subject, it first requires prefacing the idea that existence, meaning creation is broken into three general divisions, namely World (עולם), Year or Change (שנה), and Spirit (נפש). This is discussed in Sefer Midbar Kedmot by Rabbi Chaim Yoseph David Azulai and other places.
These divisions are alluded to in the Written Torah in Shemot 19:18 and 20:14 which say:

וְהַ֤ר סִינַי֙ עָשַׁ֣ן כֻּלּ֔וֹ מִ֠פְּנֵ֠י אֲשֶׁ֨ר יָרַ֥ד עָלָ֛יו יְהֹוָ֖ה בָּאֵ֑שׁ וַיַּ֤עַל עֲשָׁנוֹ֙ כְּעֶ֣שֶׁן הַכִּבְשָׁ֔ן וַיֶּחֱרַ֥ד כׇּל־הָהָ֖ר מְאֹֽד׃

and

וְכׇל־הָעָם֩ רֹאִ֨ים אֶת־הַקּוֹלֹ֜ת וְאֶת־הַלַּפִּידִ֗ם וְאֵת֙ ק֣וֹל הַשֹּׁפָ֔ר וְאֶת־הָהָ֖ר עָשֵׁ֑ן וַיַּ֤רְא הָעָם֙ וַיָּנֻ֔עוּ וַיַּֽעַמְד֖וּ מֵֽרָחֹֽק׃

That one of the earliest paradigms of existence is the division into thirds, of right (ימין), left (שמאל) and center (אמצע), also called the three Kavin (קוין) or dimensions (מאימדות). That these 3 Kavin are comprised of: the aspect of World which is conceived of as the idea of Space in the nomenclature of the natural sciences, or Place (מקום) like is used in Yalkut Shimoni to Bereshit 28:11.
The aspect of Year relates to the concept of Time in the nomenclature of the natural sciences, both non-linear time (זמן בלתי המשוער) and linear time (זמן משוער). Linear time is associated specifically to the principle of Change (משנה).
The third aspect of Existence is the  aspect of Soul which in this usage is better translated as Spirit or Spiritual. This third aspect of existence, like Space and Time, is distinct and yet all three aspects are interwoven to make up our tapestry of existence.
This paradigm of three dimensional existence is also expressed in our bodies with right hand, left hand and torso.
With this introduction, we can now consider the five aspects or dimensions  of soul mentioned in your question.
Like with our body and the five organs of the mouth (throat, pallet, tongue, teeth and lips See Sefer Yetzirah 2:3), the five fingers of each hand, and the five toes of each foot (גודל, אצבע, אמה, קמיצה, זרת), these five dimensions of Nefesh (נפש), Ruach (רוח), Neshamah (נשמה), Chayah (חיה), and Yechidah (יחידה) are consequences (תולדות) or offspring (בנים), so to speak, of their higher, general, categorical root, the Spirit (הנפש, נפש).
They are mentioned in ascending order and from the more specific and individual to the more general and inclusive.
The first three terms associated to the Spirit are restricted in proper usage to the individual. They are associated with the animating aspect (נפש,נפש הבהמית) of the soul, meaning what interacts with material, physical existence, the emotive aspect of the soul (רוח) and the intellectual aspect of soul (נשמה). These latter two categories are not capable of interacting with material existence directly, but rather influence the animating soul, which is the bridge or link between material and spiritual existence.
That the physical body (גוף) without a soul dressed within it, is considered a dead body, a corpse (פגר). So too, when the constituent parts of the individual soul are not woven together, that is death (מות). But when the individual, constituent parts of the soul remain woven together, even outside the material body, they retain the status of being alive.
And just like with the 5 parts of the mouth and the 5 fingers and toes, the remaining two aspects of the Spirit, the Chayah and Yechidah are not about the individual (יחיד), but to the collective (צבור). This is in keeping with the concept in Halacha that the Congregation doesn't die (צבור לא מת).
In this context, the distinction between the aspect of Spirit (הנפש) referred to as Chayah (חיה) and the aspect referred to as Yechidah (יחידה) are understood. That Chayah pertains to the vitality of all animate, living creations, while Yechidah is that aspect of Spirit pertaining to the vitality of all inanimate creations.
That is all the time I have currently to write. There are many textual sources that still need to be listed and linked to this answer. But this should be sufficient to understand.

Oh my goodness, a long answer from Reb Yaacov Deane! Is it Chanuka already? Can't wait to get to this soon. Don't suppose I could also get your wisdom my Rechovot question?

Getting it in before the beginning of WW III. Make sure your apartment is lined with aluminum foil to shield from the radiation! ;-)

There is no feasible way to shield one's house from radiation using basic items like tin foil. I also do not think there will be a WW III, call me a hopeless optimist :)

The tin foil is a joke my friend. On the subject of WW III, don't be so sure. There are plenty of sources for it in Torah and the prophecy of Ovadiah and what leads up to the "Great and Awesome Day of G-d" (see Yoel 3:4, Malachi 3:23 and Daniel 9:4) is the main idea. For some (who are not righteous), it could be very unpleasant. That is definitely part of the "Days of Moshiach". In that context, we have 9 years to go. We aren't even in the final Shemittah cycle yet. A lot can happen.

I know, I've seen your analysis. I still hold optimism

Only good comes from Above. Optimism is appropriate.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
